# What is a Parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, parameters

I was wondering what exactly is a parameter in PHP?

Comment: By parameter do you mean a [function argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A parameter is anything you *pass* to a function or method. It can be some value stored in a variable, or a literal value you pass on the fly. They are also known as [arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

```
some_function($some_param, "some other param");
```

It's kind of like using a blender to make a smoothie: the blender is the function, the ingredients and the milk you put in the blender to blend are the parameters/arguments, and the smoothie is the return value :)

```
$banana_smoothie = make_smoothie('banana', 'milk');
```

You can also see similar analogies in the PHP manual entry I link to (`makecoffee()` and `makeyogurt()`).